# -isKindOfClass: not working with NSCFString

Tags: objective-c, introspection

Why isn't my if-statement working? It doesn't accept NSCFStrings...
Basically I'm doing this:

```
if ([myObj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // ...
}
else if ([myObj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    //...
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid NSMutableArray.\n\tWrong type in array: %@, The value is: %@.",[myObj class], myObj);
}
```

This is inside a loop where I am iterating over an NSMutableArray, with only NSNumbers and NSStrings inside.
Strange enough, it accepts NSNumbers, but no NSStrings!
The output is always:

```
Invalid NSMutableArray.
    Wrong type in array: NSCFString, The value is: [Value I put in the string].
```

I thought NSCFString was a subclass of NSString and `-isKindOfClass:` detected subclasses too?

**UPDATE:**
I solved it myself. It was indeed caused by –– as stated by @jjv360 –– the missing else before the second if. I thought that was a typo, because I retyped it here instead of copy-pasting, *that* because I nested a few more `if-else`s and things got cluttered (that's a google translate-translation).
Pretty stupid after all.

jjv360 Please post this as an answer.

Comment: What is the `term` var in your NSLog? shouldn't it be `myObj`? (or the other way around...)

Comment: yes, you're right. I tried to make it a bit more logical by altering the var name, but I forget the logging statement.

Comment: Another thing, there's an `else` missing between the first and the second `if` statement...

Comment: Two questions: 1) why aren't you using NSStrings 2) does it work if you use NSStrings? Also, have you tried just adding an `or` statement that allows the class to be `[NSCFString class]`?

Comment: @Cake 1. I don't have a choice. With saying @"cetera" an NSCFString is automatically created. 2. NSCFString class is private.

Comment: Have you tried making your strings with `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"words"];`?

Comment: no. I will try that tomorrow. I have no access to my mac now... @Cake

Comment: but I don't think that's a good solution, though. My app will eventually take user input in there. And I don't care which type or string it is, as long as I can test if it behaves as a string. @Cake

Comment: No matter what, you should be able to use the initWithString method (even with user input). What I am confused about is why NSCFString is apparently being created by default. Post the code where your string is created? NSString is always the default for me.

Comment: @Cake No, that's not the case according to the documentation. The documentation says that there is almost never a real NSString created, and in most of the cases that it is one of NSString's subclasses it is NSCFString.

Comment: Okay, it looks like the reason your statement doesn't work is that NSCFString isn't technically a subclass of NSString, but NSString is just a wrapper. So I guess it's comparable to `isKindOfClass: [NSNumber class]` wouldn't return true for an int.

Comment: Aha. But how should I check it then?

Comment: @jjv360 please make your command about the missing else an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my comment posted as an answer:

There is a missing `else` statement between your if statements. Without it, it will run the code in the first block as well as the code in the else block at the end...